# If $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable, and $f$ is also $\mathcal{S}'$-measurable, then $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{S}'$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x^2$. Let $\mathcal{S} = \{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}): A = -A\}$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ are the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $-A = \{-a : a \in A\}$. (In other words, $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of all Borel subsets that are equal to their negative). We have previously shown that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable.

Show that if $\mathcal{S}'$ is another $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is $\mathcal{S}'$-measurable, then $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{S}'$.

As mentioned below in the comments, this means showing that $\mathcal{S}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $f$ is measurable, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What you are asked to show is precisely that $\mathcal S$ is the smallest sigma algebra

Comment: You are right. I should have known that. @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a symmetric Borel set $A=-A$. Now the function $x^2$ is a homeomorphism of $[0,\infty)$ onto $[0,\infty)$ ( $\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous inverse). Since, $A\cap [0,\infty)$ is a borel set and $x^2$ a homeomorphism on $[0,\infty)$ it follows that the image
$$B=A^{2}\cap [0,\infty)$$
of $A$ through the function $x^2$ is a Borel set too. We claim that $f^{-1}(B)=A$. Indeed,
if $x\in A$ then $f(x)=x^2 \in A^2\cap [0,\infty)=B$. Hence, $A\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$. Now, if $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ then $f(x)=x^{2}\in A^{2}\cap [0,\infty)$. In particular, $x^2\in A^2$. Hence, $x\in A$ or $x\in -A$. But since $A$ is symmetric it follows that $x\in A$. So, $f^{-1}(B)=A$. Now, since $B$ is a Borel set it follows that $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{S'}$. But, $f^{-1}(B)=A\in \mathcal{S'}$. Hence, $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{S'}$.